Is Python's map function evaluation lazy?
I've been solving LeetCode's 1331. Rank Transform of an Array challenge and came up with this one-line solution:
class Solution:
    def arrayRankTransform(self):
        return map({e: i for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(arr)), 1)}.get, arr)

It evaluates substitution dictionary and maps all element with it (something like str's translate method). But for this solution I have a question: does the dictionary evaluate only one time before looping over elements or does it re-evaluates for every element?
In other words, does map store the function before iterating or does it evaluate the function again for every element?
If you can answer, please provide reference for Python docs or source code

map() is an ordinary function. The arguments are evaluated once, their values are passed to the function.

You could have answered your own question with a print call.

btw, if your return value annotation is correct, you don't want to use map here.  If you do want to use map, the annotation is wrong.

@wim about typing annotation: yes, I know, it's intended; about print call - can you please provide a way? because if map's first argument will be a function, which prints anything, it will definitely print it for each arr's element, so, I can't see a way, how I can prove it with print call
anyway, fixed type hint ;)

Extremely minor note: Save a little work by passing 1 as the second argument to enumerate, and the dictcomp production expression becomes {e: i for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(arr)), 1)}.get (it's a micro-optimization, directly producing the int you want, rather than producing the wrong one and making a new one by adding).

@ShadowRanger, thx! will fix it

@diduk001: map(lambda x, y: print("Constructing callable"): print("Calling callable") or x, arr). If map is recreating the lambda for each item in arr, it will have to recreate the default argument y on each, causing the constructing print each time, along with the calling print. But it won't. You will see Constructing callable once when you create the map, and Calling callable only when you actually consume items from it (if you create the map, then print before looping over it, you'll see construction is before any iteration occurs).

Like map((print("foo") or {}).get, ...)

@Barmar "map() is an ordinary function." - Maybe this is pedantic, but it's actually a class. In any case, it could be implemented as a function (generator) and work exactly the same.

In the context of how parameters are processed, classes are "ordinary functions". There's just lots of stuff going on in the implementation that causes the function to initialize and return a class instance.

It creates and stores the dict's bound .get method once as each map object is constructed, not once-per-item in the iterable. It's a normal argument to a callable, map isn't a special syntactic construct, there's literally no way for Python to delay creating the dict and binding the .get method of it, any more than it could do so for a user-defined function.
This is in fact one of the rare cases where map improves meaningfully on list comprehensions/generator expressions; map receiving the mapping function as an argument means an expensive-to-create callable is only created once; if you inlined it into a listcomp or genexpr, e.g.:
class Solution:
    def arrayRankTransform(self, arr):
        return ({e: i for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(arr)), 1)}.get(x) for x in arr)

it would be created once per loop, adding quite a bit of overhead, and the only way to avoid it while still writing a genexpr would be to extract the construction to a cached value outside the genexpr, e.g.
class Solution:
    def arrayRankTransform(self, arr):
        mapping = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(sorted(set(arr)), 1)}
        return (mapping.get(x) for x in arr)

Technically, there are other tricks possible to do this as a one-liner with a genexpr that only constructs the mapping once, but they're ugly hacks; the two-liner is the way to go if you can't/won't use map and need to avoid per-item overhead.

there's literally no way ... I can think of a few ways.  They're all diabolical, though.

@wim: For this specific circumstance, the syntax in use is inherently eager. Unless you're suggesting ast hacking nonsense a la the wahaha module I've seen (where your shebang line is #!python3 -mwahaha and it's actually running a different module that then parses and runs your Python code in a semi-colon and brace delimited mode that ignores indentation levels)? I'll treat that as something that Python, the language spec, would not allow, because it stops being Python at that point, just some DSL written in Python-like syntax.

There are several ways to get in before the parser does, no custom python exe necessary.  To name a couple: import hook (sys.meta_path.insert(0, ...)), module coding declaration (there is an f-string backport which uses this trick).

@wim: Yeah, that's still a DSL in my opinion, not Python. But yes, this sort of nonsense is fun.

one of the rare cases where map improves meaningfully...  totally disagree.  The code is significantly less readable, and the return value can only be iterated once. This is no improvement at all, unless memory was a concern (doesn't look like it).

@wim, chill, it's only a leetcode problem, and I wrote one-line solution just for fun and practice. realistically, nobody should use this piece of code in any kind of production environment

@ShadowRanger thx for the answer! could you please provide some sort of proof (maybe some python sources or docs)

@diduk001 here: "All argument expressions are evaluated before the call is attempted."

@juanpa.arrivillaga ty!

@wim "and the return value can only be iterated once" - How does that differ from using a generator expression?

@Unmitigated That is a difference is with a list comprehension, not with a generator expression. A previous revision of the question annotated the return type as List[int].
